# Can I dynamically assign n variables to a string with length n?

Tags: python, string, variables

Suppose I have a (binary) string with length `n`. My goal is to assign the values of each element of the string to `n` variables: `m_1, m_2, ..., m_n`. I can do that when `n` is fixed: `m_1, m_2, m_3 ,m_4, m_5 = map(int, '10110')`.

However, I don't know how I can do that dynamically, to accommodate an arbitrary `n`. I thought about using a list comprehension, but still not sure how it works to solve this problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I create variable variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-variable-variables) - `m = list(map(int, '10110'))`, then use `m[0]`, `m[1]`, `m[2]`, etc. An equivalent list comprehension would be `m = [int(x) for x in '10110']`.